# SQL display duplicate field but not nulled field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple problem i think. I have in sql Server one table with this :

```
Name :       Sum :     CNP

Andrey       100       120
Marius       20        100
George       20        200
Popescu      Nulled    300
Antal        Nulled    100
```

I use this comand to show duplicate :

```
SELECT SUM, Name,CNP
FROM dbo.database
where SUM IN ( Select SUM from dbo.asigpag group by SUM HAVING Count(*)> 1)
```

Everything work ok.

In this Case show :

```
Name :       Sum :     CNP

Marius       20        100
George       20        200
Popescu      Nulled    300
Antal        Nulled    100

This is the problem . I want to display duplicate but with not Nulled.
```

I want to display this with all the other field not only Sum.

```
Name :       Sum :     CNP

Marius       20        100
George       20        200
```

Comment: How about:  `select * from dbo.database where [Sum] = 20`?

Comment: Why don't you use `Where is Not Null` in your query String

Comment: I cand' use where [Sum] = 20,  because if i have for example 10000 duplicate i want to show all duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another condition to exclude records that have a null value in the sum field:

```
SELECT SUM, Name,CNP
FROM dbo.database
where SUM IN ( Select SUM from dbo.asigpag group by SUM HAVING Count(*)> 1) 
AND SUM is not NULL
```

SQL Server treats NULLS differently from values, because they have no value at all. They're special case that need to be selected using `[Field] IS NULL` or `[Field] = NULL`, or their reverse, as in this case.

Comment: I try this it is ok but display same problem, nulled showing. I don't whant to display nulled, only duplicate without nulled.

Comment: This execution is ok and not showing duplicate with 0 , but i need not showing empty duplicate. In My database field is empty not 0.

Comment: I tested again, i wrong when i say is not showing duplicate with O. This command show duplicate but empty data is showing.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL NULL <> NULL always. You can use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL or predefined function ISNULL(SUM, 0) - with last statement you will prepare NULL values to default 0 value. For example:

```
SELECT SUM, Name,CNP
FROM dbo.database
where ISNULL(SUM, 0) IN ( Select ISNULL(SUM, 0) from dbo.asigpag group by SUM HAVING Count(*) > 1)
```

**Update:**

Sorry, I misunderstood what you want. In order to eliminate NULL from the list you need to update sub-query as:

```
Select SUM from dbo.asigpag where SUM IS NOT NULL group by SUM HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Whole query will be:

```
SELECT SUM, Name, CNP
FROM dbo.database
where SUM IN ( Select SUM from dbo.asigpag Where SUM IS NOT NULL group by SUM HAVING Count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: I try this it is ok but display same problem, nulled showing.

Comment: This execution is ok and not showing duplicate with 0 , but i need not showing empty duplicate. In My database field is empty not 0.

Comment: I tested again, i wrong when i say is not showing duplicate with O. This command show duplicate but empty data is showing.